# Toggle background color on button (keydown / keycodes)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, When I press the button1 "1 PLAY / STOP", the button turns green and when I press it again it removes the color.
If I press the button2 "2 PLAY / STOP" the same thing happens.

If one of the two buttons plays and I press the other, it removes the color of one and goes to the other.

I want to do the same with the Z button (button 1) and X (button 2).
For example, when I press the Z button (keycode 90) or the X button (keycode 88) to do what it does with the mouse.

And if there is better coding in all this it would be very useful because it is more than 20 buttons...
Thanks a lot!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn1, #btn2').on('click', function() {
    $('#btn1, #btn2').not(this).removeClass('colors');
    $(this).toggleClass('colors');
  });
});

 
var nowplaying = "";

function playButton1() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("1");
  play(audio);
} 

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 90){
    var audio = document.getElementById("1");
    play(audio);
  }
});


function playButton2() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("2");
  play(audio);
} 

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 88){
    var audio = document.getElementById("2");
    play(audio);
  }
});


function play(audio) { 
  if (audio != nowplaying){
    if (nowplaying != "") {
      nowplaying.pause();
    }
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play(audio);
    nowplaying = audio;
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    nowplaying = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#btn1, #btn2 {
  padding:20px 30px
}

.colors {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1" onclick="playButton1()">1 PLAY / STOP</button>

<button id="btn2" onclick="playButton2()">2 PLAY / STOP</button>

<audio id="1" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<audio id="2" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it could be better coded but it shows the idea:

```js
var nowplaying = "";

function playButton(i) {
  play($(`#${i}`).get(0));
} 

function play(audio) { 
  if (audio != nowplaying){
    if (nowplaying != "") {
      nowplaying.pause();
    }
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play(audio);
    nowplaying = audio;
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    nowplaying = "";
  }
}

$(function(){

  $('#btn1, #btn2').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btn1, #btn2').not(this).removeClass('colors');
    $(this).toggleClass('colors');
  });
  
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 90){
      $("#btn2").trigger('click');
    } else if (e.keyCode === 88) {
      $("#btn1").trigger('click');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#btn1, #btn2 {
  padding:20px 30px
}

.colors {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1" onclick="playButton(1)">1 PLAY / STOP</button>

<button id="btn2" onclick="playButton(2)">2 PLAY / STOP</button>

<audio id="1" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<audio id="2" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: I have voted up your answer as it have the same idea. Actually there are not many options. I think you should make it more jQuery like as the question uses jQuery and is tagged as jQuery. Otherwise it solves the problem which is asked.

Comment: More jQuery ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Well I saw you have edited your answer in the right direction ... so you got what I meant. Also per instance you are able to use chaining for this `btn.parent().addClass('active'); btn.toggleClass('colors');` so it will become `btn.toggleClass('colors').parent().addClass('active');` . Such things, not affecting the functionality but showing better programming skills and optimal handling.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to offend or underestimate your work - you've made it fine, but you asked what could be done more jQuery like.  Here  `btnPlays.on('click', function(e) { btnPlays.removeClass('colors'); ... })` - It will be better to use `$(this).removeClass('colors')` . You've made a good job, I'm just suggesting some final touches.

Comment: I was thinking it's easiest to understand for non-IT persons. Bad habit. Nice feedback.

Comment: No if you put $(this) instead btnPlays it will oly toggle the clicked one, not all others, so if another btnPlays on page it will stay active.. Don't know it's the logic you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right! My bad!

Comment: It's possible also to generate all the navigation with jQuery directly if you want to be full jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [new Audio()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) to create and manipulate easily your audio element.

> The Audio() constructor creates and returns a new HTMLAudioElement
> which can be either attached to a document for the user to interact
> with and/or listen to, or can be used offscreen to manage and play
> audio.

Then use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) tu store your audio src in each button.

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM.

So when you click on button, his `data-audio-src` value append to your previously created audio element.

I put button into div wich is set to active when a child button is clicked so  when you press `X` or `Z` it "detect" wich one is playing then switch the good button.

```js
let nowplaying = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  let btnPlays = $('.btn-play')
  btnPlays.on('click', function(e) {
    btnPlays.removeClass('colors');
    $('.btnHolder.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('colors').parent().addClass('active');
    play(new Audio($(this).data('audio-src')));
  })
}).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 88) {
    console.log('X')
    $('.btnHolder.active>button.btn-play:eq(0)').click()
  } else if (e.keyCode === 90) {
    console.log('Z')
    $('.btnHolder.active>button.btn-play:eq(1)').click()
  }
});
;


function play(audio) {
  if (audio != nowplaying) {
    if (nowplaying != "") {
      nowplaying.pause();
    }
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
    nowplaying = audio;
    console.log("Now playing : " + nowplaying.src);
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    nowplaying = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.btn-play {
  padding: 20px 30px
}

.colors {
  background-color: green;
}

.btnHolder.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btnHolder active">
  <button class="btn-play" id="btn1" data-audio-src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/60/60703_781423-lq.mp3">1 PLAY / STOP</button>

  <button class="btn-play" id="btn2" data-audio-src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/60/60703_781423-lq.mp3">2 PLAY / STOP</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="btnHolder">
  <button class="btn-play" id="btn3" data-audio-src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/60/60703_781423-lq.mp3">3 PLAY / STOP</button>

  <button class="btn-play" id="btn4" data-audio-src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/60/60703_781423-lq.mp3">4 PLAY / STOP</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot!!!. One more question. What about if "id =' some text' and not numbers 1 or 2. Then how could I use that line -->   play($(`#${i}`).get(0)); and that line --> onclick="playButton(1)" ? Thanks again